# Switch order of editing accessory and reorder control in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm very new to iOS development and just recently discovered editing accessories for table view cells. I'm trying to make a playlist app where, in editing mode, people can rearrange the order of the songs, or tap a song to edit its metadata.

Currently, I have disclosure indicators that only appear on the cells when the table is being edited, but they appear to the left of the reorder control: [App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskWn.png) Here's my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var rowToBeEdited: Int?
var songs: Song = [...sample data...]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "songCell", for: indexPath) as! SongCell
    let song = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.songNameLabel.text = song.name
    cell.albumNameLabel.text = song.album
    cell.artistsLabel.text = song.artists
    cell.albumImage.image = song.albumImage
    cell.editingAccessoryType = (tableView.isEditing) ? .disclosureIndicator : .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

// Add tableView functions for editing
@IBAction func editPlaylistButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    tableView.isEditing = !tableView.isEditing
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        rowToBeEdited = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailVCToEdit", sender: song)
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
}

// other code not shown...
```

}

I've seen in some apps that the two controls are switched around [(like in this app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydrMw.png) and I was wondering how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My best guess would be that they did the customization themselves..

Comment: That's what I thought too, cause it didn't seem like there was an easy way to get around this natural order of components. But I just wanted to check if there was some easy solution or hack to this that I didn't come across yet.